# Execute a bat file when an image is viewed

Tags: image, batch-file

I want to hide a bat file or its commands in a image file so when the image is opened the commands in the bat file is executed.

Comment: And this isn't malicious... how?

Comment: I came here looking for the same thing (years later) because I'm wanting to run a .bat file that just displays a funny message on their command prompt...because my friends and I like to play jokes on one another. :-) Not malicious at all.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you're speaking specifically for the windows platform (what with "batch" files), you can't.

Batch files are parsed, not compiled, so an image file with batch in it would still be read as an image file.

I really can't sum it up more clearly than things just **don't** work like this.

However, assuming you're doing things *ethically*, you *can* re-associate, say, a .jpg extension to be opened with the command prompt and put your batch script in a text file with a .jpg extension.

Just a final note: Questions like these are often looked poorly upon by the StackOverflow members simply because you're hardly ever trying to achieve something like this with good intentions. I won't be the first to flame you, but I definitely won't be the last.

Comment: I have no intention of doing harm to somebody. I want to popup a "Birthday wish" when the image is viewed.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of ways in which a single file can contain two distinct streams of data which are independent of, and don't interfere with, each other. [One commonly cited example](http://linux-hacks.blogspot.com/2009/02/theory-behind-hiding-zipped-file-under.html) of this is how it is possible to append a .zip file to a .jpg file and still have the combined file function as both types of files, depending on what sort of application is opening it. This trick takes advantage of the specific way jpeg and zip files are structured. These sorts of files are akin to [polyglot program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_%28computing%29).

Another common method of embedding unrelated information into a file is [steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography), which is the concealment of messages within mundane objects (like an image file.)

You might also consider using an [Alternate Data Stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28file_system%29#NTFS), though in such a case the batch file would arguably not be embedded *in* the image.

Once you have your batch file embedded, by whatever means, you must then find a way to cause the batch file to be run instead of--or in addition to--whichever image-viewing application the user has configured.

It can be safe to assume that the average user does not expect a file ending in .jpg (for example) to open a cmd.exe window and start executing unknown instructions. Windows Explorer, the application which under most circumstances decides what program to run when a certain file type is double clicked, has sane defaults (i.e. a .jpg file gets opened with an image viewing application) though these can be changed (though users generally don't change these sane defaults to insane customizations like cmd.exe.)

The simplest method would be to write your own handler program and cause it to become the default handler for image file types. I believe that all handler applications must be compiled PE application or library files (`.exe`, `.dll`, `.scr`, etc.) so another batch file won't work here. Your custom handler must reverse the embedding to retrieve the embedded batch file and then execute it with cmd.exe.

But if you've already managed to supplant the default handler with your own code then the embedded batch file is moot since you've already got your code running.

---

I have to echo what @Di-0xide said about this question. If you're trying to write a legitimate application and this is part of your design plan, then you need to go back to the drawing board because no legitimate application should **ever** do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Although there are no doubt many more malace reasons why someone would want to embed a batch file within an image, 
and have it execute when the image is opened. I can see at least one legitimate reason for wanting to perform the task.

What if you have a family computer, shared with your 2 kids, the wife, and yourself. Lets say you have some files you don't 
want your children to come across, or a directory full of journal entries. It would be pretty neat if a simple batch file that would 
change the attributes settings of the directory, containing the sensitive files. This way a parent could rest assure that their 
kids wont stumble upon dads nudie pics. LOL

IE:  Lets say someone wrote 2 simple batch files s.bat(to show the directory) and h.bat(to hide the directory)

hide.bat

```
@echo off
REM Show the directory containing sensitive info:
attrib +a +s +h +r C:\path\to\the\directory\to\hide

REM Hide this batch file(or image containing the batch file):
attrib +a +s +h +r C:\path\to\the\batch\files\hide.bat

REM Show a batch file(or image containing the batch file) that will allow for showing the directory:
attrib -a -s -h -r C:\path\to\the\batch\files\show.bat
```

show.bat

```
@echo off
REM Show the directory containing sensitive info:
attrib -a -s -h -r C:\path\to\the\directory\to\hide

REM Show the batch file(or image containing the batch file) that will allow user to hide directory:
attrib -a -s -h -r C:\path\to\the\batch\files\h.bat

REM Hide this batch file(or image containing the batch file):
attrib +a +s +h +r C:\path\to\the\batch\files\s.bat
```

I think it would work better having images that would execute the show.bat and hide.bat batch files, rather than just changing the icon on each batch file.

Perhaps writing a handler program that would change the attributes of the directory then open the image and associate the handler to some unused extension, would work.

Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do this is to just create your batch file as normal and then create a desktop shortcut of the  same batch file. Finally right-click on the shortcut and change the icon to what ever image you want. Once all changes are made then anytime the image is opened,  the batch file will run.

Comment: I am not sure this is what Udara wanted. This only runs the batchfile if the link on thedesctop is opened - not if the image file is opened. Theres an easy distinction between an image and a .lnk file.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy just use winrar archive to embed bat file in image. This will run bat file before image or you can change settings to run image file before bat.

Follow this tutorial to do so:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytvKVYYrqEw